# dropdown-list of custom combobox in Delphi is closing right after comming up

Tags: delphi, combobox, richedit

I was looking for an easy way to use RichtText in a default combobox, but found nothing.
So I wrote this little Delphi(7) component, that is working so far.

How is works:
I'm calling "init" to replace the "Edit"-window inside a default combobox with a
runtime-created RichEdit. Size is taken from the Edit, and Edit is finally hidden.
Some event-handlers are included for change-detection and so on.

Problem:
If I click an item of the dropdown-list, the text is shown in the RichEdit.
If some text is entered inside the RichEdit and the dropdown-button is pressed again,
the dropdown-list is opened and closed in the next moment. After some clicks, the list
remains open and is working as expected. 
Every time I click the list and change the RichEdit again, the same is happening.

Maybe I have to sent some messages to the combobox to get that fixed ?

I didn't find any solution on the web, so far. Maybe you have an idea.

Thanks for your help !

```
unit RichTextComboBox;

interface

uses  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls, Windows, Messages, forms, Graphics, ComCtrls;

type
    TRichTextComboBox = class(TComboBox)
    private
        FOnChange     :TNotifyEvent;
        EditHandle :Integer;
        procedure proc_FOnComboChange(Sender: TObject);
    protected
    public
        Rich :TRichEdit;             // accessable from outside
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
        destructor  Destroy; override;
        procedure   Init;            // replace Edit in combobox with RichEdit
    published
    end;

procedure Register;

implementation



constructor TRichTextComboBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);
end;


// click in Combo-Drop-Down-List
procedure TRichTextComboBox.proc_FOnComboChange(Sender :TObject);
begin
    if Rich.Text <> Items.Strings[ItemIndex] then begin
        Rich.Text:=  Items.Strings[ItemIndex];
    end;
    if assigned (FOnChange) then FOnChange(sender);
end;


procedure Register;
begin
    RegisterComponents('TEST', [tRichTextComboBox]);
end;


destructor TRichTextComboBox.Destroy;
begin
    if Rich <> nil then begin
        RemoveControl(rich);
        Rich.destroy;
    end;
    inherited Destroy;
end;


// Replace "Edit" with "RichEdit" in ComboBox
//
procedure TRichTextComboBox.init;
var       h      :integer;
          rect   :trect;
          wndpos :TWindowPlacement;
begin
    h:= FindWindowEx(
        self.Handle,
        0,              // handle to a child window
        'Edit',         // class name
        nil
    );

    Rich:= TRichEdit.create(self);
    rich.Parent:= self;

    if h <> 0 then begin
        EditHandle:= h;
        GetWindowRect(h, rect);

        // configure RichEdit

        GetWindowPlacement(h, @wndpos);        // RichEdit with position and size of Edit
        rich.BorderStyle:= bsNone;
        rich.Text:= self.Text;
        rich.Font.Style:= [fsbold, fsItalic];
        rich.Top:=   wndpos.rcNormalPosition.top;
        rich.Left:=  wndpos.rcNormalPosition.Left;
        rich.Width:= rect.Right - rect.Left;
        rich.Height:= rect.Bottom-rect.Top;
        rich.WantReturns:= false;              // just one line
        rich.WordWrap:= false;                 // just one line
        rich.ParentColor:= true;               // just one line
        rich.Visible:= true;
        showwindow(h, sw_hide);                // hide Edit
    end;

    // if drop-down-combo-list is clicked
    // change the string of the RichEdit
    FOnChange:=     self.OnChange;             // save original OnChange of ComboBox
    rich.OnChange:= FOnChange;
    self.OnChange:= proc_FOnComboChange;
end;

end.
```

Comment: This approach seems pretty much doomed to failure to me. Why don't you custom draw the rich text.

Comment: I already tried custom draw.
Setting ComboBox.style to csOwnerDrawFixed the Edit is no longer editable.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution :-)

The RichEdit is holding the Focus, which causes the drop-down-list not to stay open after entering s.th. in the RichEdit.
This procedure sets the Focus back to the Combobox before it is opening. So everything works as expected.

---

Code to be inserted:

after `protected` enter:

```
procedure DropDown; override;
```

the procedure looks like this:

```
procedure TRichTextComboBox.DropDown;
begin
  Self.SetFocus;
  inherited DropDown;
end;
```

---

I prefer this approach, because I don't want to mess around with the OwnerDraw-problems that we can read on many pages. (Some things are still missing: Upkey/Downkey...)